# compiler warning for 32bit to 64 bit conversion

Tags: casting, long-integer, compiler-warnings, vxworks

I want to do something like this:

```
UINT32 ports[2];
UINT64 puint64 = 0;    
puint64= (UINT64)ports[1]<<32 | ports[0];
```

But I get a warning:

> warning (etoa:2273): suspicious truncation of a 32-bit value when assigned to a 64-bit integral type (potential portability problem)

Why is this, and how can I avoid it?

**Edit 1**

This is WindRiver's diab compiler.

**Edit 2**

Changing the code to use `puint64= ((UINT64)ports[1])<<32 | (UINT64)ports[0];` didn't help get rid of the warning. `UNIT64` is a typedef for `unsigned long long`, which should be correct.

Any ideas?

**Edit 3**

This is on `VxWorks 6.9`

Comment: What compiler are you using? I just compiled this with `gcc` and `clang` with full warnings and they didn't have a problem with it [and generated correct code]? The only way I was able to get an error was to change the typedef for `UINT64` from `unsigned long long` to `unsigned int`. Are you sure the typedefs you have are correct?

Comment: Actually, there is one other way: `puint64 = (UINT64) (ports[1]<<32) | ports[0];` By adding the extra parentheses, the warning shows up. So, this would imply that the compiler [without the parens] was grouping it this way.

Comment: @CraigEstey see **Edit 1** above

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UINT32 ports[2];
UINT64 puint64;
puint64 = (((UINT64)ports[1]) << 32) | ((UINT64)ports[0]);
```

Notice the additional parenthesis around each operation.

---

*Edit*: since you are still getting the warning, I suggest you break up each operation and figure out exactly which one is causing the warning:

```
UINT32 ports[2];
UINT64 puint64;

UINT64 high = (UINT64) ports[1];
high <<= 32;

UINT64 low = (UINT64) ports[0];

puint64 = high | low;
```

Comment: No, same thing: `suspicious truncation of a 32-bit value when assigned to a 64-bit integral type (potential 
 portability problem)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are shifting a 32bit value by 32 bits.

You have tried to cast to UINT64,  but the cast is of the shifted value, not the Value you are shifting.

You need to cast then shift eg:

```
Uint32 a;
UINT64 b=((UINT64)a)<<32;
```

Comment: I will expand on answer tomorrow when I am not on the mobile app

Comment: That's eactly what I have with `puint64= (((UINT64)ports[1])<<32) | ((UINT64)ports[0]);`, isn't it?

Comment: I still think there is a precedence issue, but I can't quite put my figure on it. Let me try tomorrow.

Comment: This is on `VxWorks 6.9`. A precedence issue, really...? I don't see how... :o

Comment: Which build target are you using? I cant reproduce the warning with your original code (using PENTIUM4diab)

Comment: I'm building using `e500v2diab_ppc85XX_e500v2`

Comment: Ah, I dont have PPC support installed